# Does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(1-p_i)$ converge to $-\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(1-p_i)$ converge to $-\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i$ for $0 \le p_i < 1$?

The series expansion of $\ln(1-p_i) = -p_i-\dfrac{p_i^2}{2}-\dfrac{p_i^3}{3}-\ldots=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{p_i^j}{j}$.  Thus, we have $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(1-p_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{p_i^j}{j}$$

Then what's next? Thanks you!

Comment: What are the $p_i$?

Comment: @jacky123456789 are the $p_i$ probabilities?

Comment: I've edited the question. I forgot to mention that $0\le p_i < 1$

Comment: A simple counter-example: $p_1 = 1/2$ and $p_i=0$ for $i>1$ shows that $\sum \log(1-p_i) \not = - \sum p_i$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $p_i = \frac {1}{2^i}$. Then the right hand side is $-1$ (sum of a geometric series), whereas the left hand side is $\approx -1.24206$ according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20i%3D1%20to%20i%3Dinfinity%20ln%281-%281%2F2%29%5Ei%29)